# MongoDB- how to pass expression to $limit operator in aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, limit, aggregation

i need to pass a variable to $limit operator but it accepts only integers

example

```
collection = [
{
_id : ObjectId(id1)
count : 20
total : 3
},
{
_id : ObjectId(id2)
count : 12
total : 3
},
{
_id : ObjectId(id3)
count : 9
total : 3
}
    ]
```

and if we limit the the collection to 1/3 of `total` to get only one document in the collection so we need to pass an expression to `$limit` and that's not possible in mongoDB cause the last accepts only integers values ... ***how to solve ?***

Comment: How do you get 2.5678 documents? Conver to integer (int)(total/3) and pass it to limit.

Comment: i m wiling to pass expression to limit to make more dynamic for example if total is 12 i should get 4 documents only 
in another collection if the total is 15 i should get 5 
i don't want to hard code an integer

Answer (score 1):

the solution to such problem is to push all documents of the collection to an array and slice it then unwind it

```js
 //this will push all your docs into data
 $facet: {
            metadata: [
              {
               <expression>
              },
            ],
            data: [
              {
                $addFields: {
                  "_": null,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        },

        {
          $unwind: {
            path: "$metadata",
          },
        },

        {
          $addFields: {
            ratio: <expression>
          },
        },
// slicing the data 
        {
          $project: {
            name: 1,
            slicedArray: {
              $slice: ["$data", "$ratio"],
            },
          },
        },

        {
          $unwind: {
            path: "$slicedArray",
          },
        },

        {
          $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$slicedArray",
          },
        },
```